# Replace unwanted value with the preceding value in the list

Tags: python, loops, pandas, replace

I have the following `signalId` in a dataframe(`df`). I am trying to smooth this signal while replacing unwanted signalId's

In the following example, 
a) 6th Id `03` should be replaced by `01`
b) 12th and 13th (`04` and `05` respectively) should be replaced by `02`

```
01
01
01
01
01
03
01
01
02
02
02
04
05
02
02
02
```

I can replace the value if I know the exact location, but how to loop through to do this?

```
df.id.loc[6] = 01
```

Comment: Is there a logic? Like difference between two rows should not exceed some threshold, etc?

Comment: No such logic, Kartik. I can have signal 51 right after 01 - However, I have to clean/replace the unexpected values. It should be series of 1's, 2's etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the trick... assuming the logic to determine that 3,4,5 were invalid is that they are > than 2.

you may need to make some adjustments to your logic to find the value that is out of place, but the rest of the procedure below should work. Basically find the invalid value, set the nan. then ffill() at the end.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.Series([51,51,1,51,51,1,1,2,1,1,1,48,48,2,48,
                  1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,4,5,2,2,2])

# answer is 2, 7, 13, 19, 25, 26

# size 1 gaps. 
# get the next value, 
data_pr = data.shift(-1)
data_nx = data.shift(1)

# % exclude the first 2 items from the filder. 
data_nx[:1]= data[:1]
data_pr[-1:] = data[-1:]
#data_lag2[:2]= data[:2]

# % find the idx where data != data_lag1 && data == data_lag2
data[(data != data_pr) & (data != data_nx) & (data_pr == data_nx) ]=np.nan
# % get invalid values that are 2 in a row... 
data_pr2 = data.shift(-2) 
data_nx2 = data.shift(2)   
data[(data != data_pr) & (data != data_nx) & (data_pr2 == data_nx2) ]=np.nan
# %
assert (data[data.isnull()].index.values == np.array([2,7,13,19,25,26])).all()
data.ffill(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Pab, This will solve if the ids are in increasing order. I may have `[51,51,1,51,51,1,1,2,1,1,1,48,48,2,48]`

Comment: how do you define that this id is "incorrect"? or needs to be removed?
is it ids that are on a black list or not in a white list? is it variance? is it non consecutive occurences?

Comment: Its non consecutive occurrences - Deviation from valid signalling.

Comment: I modified the code the run on the combination of both examples. 
It can handle one or 2 non-consecutive items...

Comment: Thank you, Prob. This really helps !!